# C# WPF - String (stored in Database) From/To RichTextBox

Tags: c#, database, xaml, binding, richtextbox

I spent my day searching on the internet a solution to my problem without success ... That seems simple enough in theory.

I have a RichTextBox in XAML.
I have in my database a field named "content" type "LongText"

I just want my database saves the contents of the RichTextBox with simple style (bold, italic, underline) and that I can call my database, fill my RichTextBox content stored in my database while keeping the style of the text.

After that, I'll have to show these data as a blog but ... must already successfully save and load data.

XAML :

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="nameTextEditor" TabIndex="2" Grid.Row="2" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
```

C#

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(monArticle.Content);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
        Section sec = XamlReader.Parse(monArticle.Content) as Section;
        while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
        {
            var block = sec.Blocks.FirstBlock;
            sec.Blocks.Remove(block);
            doc.Blocks.Add(block);
        }
        nameTextEditor.Document = doc;
```

Don't work with error :
"Exception XamlParseException"
"Données non valides au niveau racine. Ligne 1, position 1."

This is not the only code I tried but I test without understanding a word ... Why it is not so easy to "take the contents of the RichTextBox" and "send in my database"?!

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var doc = rtb.Document;
    var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    range.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var rtfString=new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
```

Now send rtfString to the database.
To display it back in the richtext box:

```
var doc = rtb.Document;
var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
sw.Write(rtfString);
sw.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
range.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it tomorrow on job-time

Comment: ... (precision) with littles modifications